# How to save uploaded files outside node js docker container (i.e. inside linux host machine)?

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, express, docker-compose

I am running an express api server inside a docker container. Now when I try to upload file using `multer` by setting `dest` param as `/` it gets uploaded somewhere inside docker container (most likely `/dist/api/`).

The API is running from dist so a console log of `__dirname` gives me `/dist/api/` which is inside docker container not in real host. I need to upload the file inside `/home/uploads/images/`. How can I acheive that? Maybe this is easy but I don't have a good knowledge in docker.

**Docker File For API**

```
FROM node:8.10

# Set a timezone
ENV TZ=UTC
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

COPY . .  
RUN yarn install  
RUN yarn run build  
CMD node dist  

HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=30s --retries=50 \
CMD curl -f localhost:8080/api || exit 1
```

**Docker Compose File**

`webapi:
    depends_on:
      serviceapi:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal_network
    build: ./api/
    expose:
      - "8080"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"`

**File Upload Code**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
         cb(null, '/home/uploads/images/')
     },
     filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.post('/profile', upload.any(), function (req, res, next) {  
     //logic goes over here
})
```

Comment: docker volumes is the answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can map a folder of your host machine to your conatainer ,

Docker Compose File

```
webapi:
    depends_on:
      serviceapi:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal_network
    build: ./api/
    volumes:
      - "/home/uploads/images/:/folder/in/container"
    expose:
      - "8080"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Comment: What should the Dockerfile look like?

Comment: same as previous. I belive the example here is docker-compose.yml file